Roughly how many organizations are considered terrorist by the UK but not (formally so) by the US?
I noticed that Jamaat-ul-Mujahideen Bangladesh is listed as a terrorist organization by the UK (and Australia) but apparently not by the US. I'm guessing the UK listed them in part because Dhaka complained about JMB receiving funds from expats in London.
I'm curious how unusual such a case is, when the UK declares some foreign organization terrorist even though the US doesn't (bother to do so). Is there an approximate number how many organizations are in such a situation, i.e on the UK's but not any of the US' terrorism lists? (I made that plural because IIRC the US has more than one designation/list for such.)

For a start, none of the 14 proscribed organisations related to Terrorism in Ireland are listed by the USA.

Beyond that, it is mostly a simple, but time consuming matter of going through https://www.state.gov/foreign-terrorist-organizations/ and https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/proscribed-terror-groups-or-organisations--2/proscribed-terrorist-groups-or-organisations-accessible-version#list-of-proscribed-international-terrorist-groups  and comparing (made harder by the fact that some organisations may not really exist any more or may be listed under different names)

@JamesK: the US lists the "New Irish Republican Army (formerly Real IRA)" as well as the "Continuity Irish Republican Army (CIRA)" though. I guess the UK doesn't consider these distinct enough from the "Irish Republican Army" as a whole, which they list. Possibly CIRA is called "Continuity Army Council" in the UK list.

Yeah, checking out  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_Irish_Republican_Army "Continuity Army Council" is the name of their leadership council.
